# Java command line console and switch

Tags: java, switch-statement, command-line-arguments

i have the following problem: i want to read in a String from the user, so far it works pretty well but everytime i press just "return" i get alway the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at Shell.execute(Shell.java:20)
    at Shell.main(Shell.java:55)
```

This would be the code:

```
private static void execute(BufferedReader stdin) throws IOException {
    boolean quit = false;
    Field test = new Field();
    while (!quit) {
        System.out.print("ch> ");
        String input = stdin.readLine();
        if (input == null) {
                break;
        }
        String[] tokens = input.trim().split("\\s+");
        tokens[0].toLowerCase();
        char tmp = tokens[0].charAt(0);
        switch (tmp) {
        case 'n':
                test.setPoints(null);
                break;
        case 'a':
                test.add(new Point(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]), Integer
                        .parseInt(tokens[2])));
                break;
        case 'r':
                test.remove(new Point(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]), Integer
                        .parseInt(tokens[2])));
                break;
        case 'p':
                System.out.println(test);
                break;
        case 'c':
                System.out.println(test.convexHull());
                break;
        case 'h':
                System.out.println("");
                break;
        case 'q':
                quit = true;
                break;
        default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Note also that `tokens[0].toLowerCase()` does not actually do anything. Strings are invariant in Java, so you cannot modify them. You need to store the result of that method, e.g. `tokens[0] = token[0].toLowerCase()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get an index out of bounds exception when accessing the 0th element, you string is probably empty. You need to add a check for this, checking for null is not enough.

By the way, when you write like this:

```
tokens[0].toLowerCase();
```

I highly suspect your tokens[0] remains unchanged. Since strings in java are immutable, toLowerCase will have to return a new string which only contains lower case character.

Answer (score 0):

See whether your `tokens` array is populated with any strings after splitting because I think that is creating problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your input String is empty if you pressed return change your code as follows to fix it.

```
while (!quit) {
     System.out.print("ch> ");
     String input = stdin.readLine();
     if (input == null && input.length()<1) { //changed line!
          break;
     }
      String[] tokens = input.trim().split("\\s+");
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the problem

```
String input = stdin.readLine();
        if (input == null) {
                break;
        }
```

here pressing "return" doesn't give you the null and your if condition fails.

code fails at below line

```
tokens[0].toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is clear user input is empty string. Put empty string check before splitting it.

```
if (input == null && input.isEmpty()) {
    break;
}
```